# Could not proxy request /user/register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3002/

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[image]

[image]Here back-end project the port is `3002` & front-end port is default `3000` which are different , i added `"proxy": "http://localhost:3002"` in react project
still getting the `proxy issue` i don't understand the issue here

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Share you package.json for frontend and backend

Comment: Share console.log(response) result

Comment: If I understand your problem you want to get the data from API and display it on the frontend

Comment: yes i want to save the input data through api call ,here console.log is not printing

Comment: Share the package.json for both

Comment: added the screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install concurrently by using npm i concurrently

then add below scripts to your backend pakage.json

This will allow you to run your backend and frontend servers at the same time.

```
    "start": "node server",    
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run client\"",
```

Then run npm run dev in backend application directory to run the application

Comment: is front end backend connection happening with these changes